# Are all Android phones good for accessibility?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

Can you recommend Android phones that are better for a visually impaired person?

Answer (score 3):

All phones ever since 1.6 have been accessible. However 2.0 and later (and especially 2.2) are much better at it. I think you'll be safe with any phone 2.0 or later (which is almost all of them now-a-days).